# Fire an event when component is opened

Tags: angular

I want to trigger an event when a corresponding event is opened. Let me explain the scenario.

This is my component selector

```
<app-sadad class="knet-div" [payMethod]="'knet'"></app-sadad>
```

Inside my component, I have used reactive form, if payMethod = Knet, I have to validators.required to particular formControl(olpid).

```
this.sadadForm = new FormGroup({
          'olpid': new FormControl(''),
          'firstName': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      });
```

I have tried ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit which didn`t get fired on form load. Kindly tell me the event which gets fired on particular form load.

Comment: Can you provide a Stackblitz event ?

Comment: do you want more code info